# combine mulitples within a phparray

Tags: php

I'm looking to count the number of multiple/repeated items in an array, combine them, and print a list of "counted" items...

So, if the array is....

```
array("apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "orange", "peach");
```

I want to end up with the following...

```
$result = "2 apples, 1 banana, 3 oranges and 1 peach";
```

Or course, the above is just an example. The array can be really long, and can be any number of items (vegetables, gems, etc.). Not so worried about gramatical plural issues (topaz plural isn't topazs, it's topazes).

Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is too broad. Have a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Use the `array_count_values()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic example without worrying about plural:

```
$array = array("apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "orange", "peach");
$occurences = array_count_values($array);
$result = "";

foreach ($occurences as $key => $val) {
    $result = $result.$val." ".$key.", ";
}

$result = substr($result, 0, -2);
echo $result;
```

Output: 2 apple, 1 banana, 3 orange, 1 peach

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic "gimme-code" type of questions. Doing that just validates them, making the OP and future visitors to keep asking them. SO isn't meant as a free coding service so we all need to help out not turning it into one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm really bored:

```
$result = array_count_values($array);
array_walk($result, function(&$v, $k) { $v = "$v $k"; });
$result = implode(', ', $result);
```

Count the values, map and concatenate the value and key then join on comma.  You have to work out the plurals for yourself, which is not straightforward and probably not needed.